# Problem due to using RETURN in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return

I have written a stored procedure. In it I want to check a condition, and if that condition turns true then I don't want to proceed for the remaining part of the stored procedure.

If that returns false, then I want to continue the remaining part of the stored procedure.

My stored procedure is here:

```
    IF (@RefPOID <> 0)
    BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(// SELECT STATEMENT)
    BEGIN
    SET @Status = 'Please select the Items'                 
        RETURN
    END 
END 
    IF(POID = 0)
    BEGIN

           //INSERTION

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

           //DELETION

    END
```

This stored procedure had compiled successfully. But while calling this stored procedure from the front end, it shows the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   severe error occurred on the current
>   command. The results, if any, should
>   be discarded.

If I removed the RETURN statement from the stored procedure, then its working fine.

If the condition turns false, the stored procedure is working fine when I call from the front end.

But I want to check the condition there and to return if it is true.

I am sure problem arise due to the presence of RETURN.

Why the problem arise? What had gone wrong? How to solve this? Any suggestion please.

Comment: You're using `RETURN` in the middle of a transaction - you might need to add a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` before the `RETURN` to properly terminate that running transaction...

Comment: Very true. Check <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=SQL.90).aspx> for details of using TRY CATCH in T-SQL. There is a section in this link entitled "TRY…CATCH with RAISERROR" and <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx> has a section entitled "B. Using TRY…CATCH in a transaction" that provide useful examples.

Comment: @marc: yes marc. what u said was absolutely true. thank you.

Comment: @Moose: thank you so much moose. you are right. thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @gbn: yes. I just mention the functionality of the sp.

Comment: No probs. Glad it was of some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending for the status to indicate a failure, then I'd be tempted to either perform the validation check prior to calling this stored proc or use RAISERROR within a TRY CATCH block.

```
BEGIN TRY

IF (@RefPOID <> 0)
BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Item I WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT P.ItemID FROM PUR_POIndent P WHERE P.ItemID = I.ItemID AND P.D1 = I.D1 AND P.D2 = I.D2 AND P.D3 = I.D3 AND P.POID = @RefPOID))
          BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Please select Items only related to the Reference Purchase', 16, 1)
          RETURN
      END  
END

...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                   @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                   @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                       @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                       @ErrorState -- State.
                        );
END CATCH
```

Comment: @Moose: I had mention the error in my Question what I get while calling from the Front End.

Comment: @thevan: Take a look at the "Remarks" section of <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=SQL.90).aspx> and you'll see how raiserror works. It states, "The errors generated by RAISERROR operate the same as errors generated by the Database Engine code", so you'll end up with a SQLException. You have the ability to assign a user defined error number using RAISERROR that you could check for in your SQLException if necessary. I think it is the "Number" property of the SQLException class. See <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your return is the problem. The query might be invalid.
But you said it works if you remove the return. That is strange.

Could you please post the complete code?

Have you tried to run in in query analyzer or studio manager?

You have:

```
SELECT 1 FROM @Item
```

Is this valid? What is @Item - a table variable?

Comment: Yes it is a table variable. that query is working fine. If i remove the RETURN then the Stored Procedure is working.

Comment: Are you expecting any numeric return value in your app?

Comment: @Projapati: I edited my Question. In that I posted my full Stored Procedure. It may look long. But I need your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Have you initialized all out variables before your first return? If not, please set all output variable with some dummy values at the beginning of the procedure. Hope that will fix this.

Comment: @Projapati: I got the answer. I didnt rollback before using RETURN. thank you for your contribution.